# Mvc JQuery Datatables. Adding checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, mvc.jquery.datatables

I'm a bit confused, is there a way to add checkbox to each row, using [JQuery Datatables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvc.JQuery.Datatables/). I want to select some rows and add bulk-update functionality. It would be fantastic if there was some way to "keep in mind" selected rows from all pages — not only from current one. There is no functionality that I want on the [sample page](http://aspdatatables.azurewebsites.net/) and it seems like all feater are presented there. So, does anyone have any ideas?

[This](http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) is exactly what I want to archive, is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean "keep in mind?"  From what I see on the sample page, it already keeps the selections between pages.  I'm using chrome, by the way.

Comment: Hi I'm the author of  Mvc.Jquery.Datatables - it doesn't currently support that checkboxes plugin, you would have to extend the library. Which isn't impossible! It's a collaborative project, and reasonably easy to extend, or it could be done by me if your company has some budget.

Comment: Those are the open-source projects... I'm solving that issue on my own. So, thanks, at least I've completely figured the problem I got.